# Passing Parameters to SQLDF in Python

Tags: python, parameters, sqldf

I'm trying to pass parameters through sqldf in python:

```
id = '001F5'
q = """select * from df where id= %id; """
test = sqldf(q, globals())
```

I've tried many things e.g. +id, "+id;"" and %id etc and nothing works, is it possible to do this at all?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
id = "'001F5'"
q = "select * from df where id=" + id + ";"
test = sqldf(q, globals())
```

Or you can try:

```
id = "'001F5'"
q = "select * from df where id={0};".format(id)
test = sqldf(q, globals())
```

Comment: let say i have to get the specific column, can i pass those column names as argument also.

Comment: @anuragpandey you'd have to build the `q` format string to incorporate the column names, e.g. `q = "select {my_col} from df".format(my_col='Column1')`. If it's multiple columns, then add the column names into a list and then set `my_col = ','.join(my_list)`.

Comment: Thanks for response @Scratch'N'Purr